# Realign wrapfigure

Tags: wrapfigure

How can I adjust the margins from the following picture in that way that W, X, Y and Z have the same distance? Additionally if I would delete the label with respect to X or W I want that this affects the margin as well. That means the distance should be smaller for the highness of the word "Label". And I'm not sure if the margins A and B are equal.

[image]

I found different properties to setup the margins like `\intextsep` and `\columnsep` but I don't know a proper value which I have to pass those variables. Please see the working example below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
%
%
\blindtext[1]%
\setlength{\intextsep}{-3pt}%
\setlength{\columnsep}{-10pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{9cm}
%\vspace{-15pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale=0.8,xmin=0,ymin=1.5, y dir=reverse,
    title={Label}, 
   xlabel={Label}, 
   ylabel={Label}]
\addplot[ mark=*, only marks
    ] table [% Provide data as a table
     ] {
x   y   
4   2.3
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\vspace{-2pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent \blindtext[4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing Y also increases X, so had to use `\intextsep=0pt`.  Z cannot be controlled precisely since it depends on where the next line of text shows up, but this forces **at least** a 10pt gap.

The `\fbox` is just to show the border.  It isn't needed (unlike the `\nopar`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\nopar}{\bgroup\parfillskip=0pt\hrule height0pt\egroup}

\begin{document}
%
%
\blindtext[1]\nopar
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\columnsep}{10pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale=0.8,xmin=0,ymin=1.5, y dir=reverse,
    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs: 0.5)},rotate=90,above,inner sep=0pt},
    every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs: 0.5)},below,inner sep=0pt},
    every axis title/.style={at={(rel axis cs: 0.5,1)},above=6pt,inner sep=0pt},
    title={Label},
   xlabel={Label}, 
   ylabel={Label}]
\addplot[ mark=*, only marks
    ] table [% Provide data as a table
     ] {
x   y   
4   2.3
};
\end{axis}
\path (current bounding box.south) ++(0pt,-10pt);% add 10pt to bottom
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{wrapfigure}
\vspace{10pt}\noindent \blindtext[4]

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]